# gpg - Find the type of decrypted file

Tags: python, encryption, gnupg

We get different kind of files (csv, xlsx, txt) from different clients. Then we have python scripts that read those files, decrypt them, do some processing, generate results and send forward to the relevant end users. Below is the command that decrypts a file to csv.

```
gpg --batch --passphrase 'my pass phrase' -o 'my_decrypted_file.csv' -du 'myuser@test.com' 'encrypted_file.pgp'
```

The encryption occurs fine. But the problem is that we don't know if the decrypted file is csv, xlsx or txt file.

Is there anyway possible using gpg or python to find out the actual type of the decrypted file?

I know you can say that I should ask clients to name the encrypted files in a way that we should be able to find out the type at the time of decryption:
Like

```
encrypted_file.csv.pgp
encrypted_file.xlsx.pgp
encrypted_file.txt.pgp
```

but in my case the above is not possible now as there are many clients and many users. And we somehow need to find the type at the time of decryption on our side.

Comment: On UNIX like operating systems you have the `file` tool to identify a file.

Comment: In general, determining the type of a file isn't possible. You can use the `file` command to make a pretty good guess, as it examines the contents of the file and tries to identify it using a database of rules. That's why file extensions or file metadata is used to *tag* a file with its type, so a reader will know how to parse it.

Comment: If your client wants you to use the files, they should be providing some way to identify the type.

Comment: On which operating system is this running? The cmd` tag is for Microsoft Windows cmd.exe. The `bash` tag is typically for UNIX/Linux/Mac, but could be Windows using WSL, Cygwin, etc.

Comment: @lit thanks for pointing out. I am executing shell commands from python. Although for testing the commands, I use both CMD and Bash. I have removed the bash and cmd tags from the question.

Comment: I take it that you would like for this to be able to run on any operating system that is running Python. Is that correct? I am not sure that will make a solution easier. I think you are better off following @chepner advice to get the provider to identify the type of data being sent.

Comment: @lit yes that's correct. Python scripts will be run linux and windows servers. You are right. We have no way but to ask the client to name the files in a format that can help us identify the type of file. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I think that something could be written that would usually identify a file correctly. The problem is that "usually" is not a good plan. It would be a constant maintenance problem and occasional surprises lay in wait to attack.